# SSH Tunneling From Mac to Windows Server 2008

Tags: mac, macos, networking, ssh

I've been using Bitvise Tunnelier for a good few years to get secure access to my home server. This week I've switched to OS X and can't seem to find a nice GUI-based app to allow me to connect SSH/SFTP/Remote Desktop thru an SSH tunnel. Can anyone please advise? I'm not overly keen on the command line...

Thanks for reading :-D

Answer (score 2):

Jellyfissh 
http://www.grepsoft.net/jellyfissh.html

It's a GUI frontend to ssh. Not sure about SFTP support though, you'll have to call upon Google for that one.

Comment: 1 second! darn. +1

Comment: Looks good, will give it a try. Thanks. (Sorry can't vote you up as have just joined superuser)